# Report "Too minor edit"?

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to report an edit being approved that was too minor? I don't yet have 2k rep so I can't roll back (and a better edit was made on top of [the particular post I'm thinking of](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24759296/revisions) anyways), but I feel like this particular edit approval is particularly egregious. All the edit did was change one spelling mistake in the title, while leaving several spelling mistakes in the post as well as the code in the post being improperly formatted.

Comment: 2 suggested edits both leaving "coading" misspelled (didn't even bother reading on from there), editors and reviewers at their finest. But the answer is no, there's nothing to do in this situation.

Comment: If you see it as a pattern for a specific user then you should flag one of the submission's posts with a custom mod flag explaining (incl. whatever links you have) what you believe the user is doing wrong. If it's just a one off then don't worry too much. Once you get +2k rep you can roll back crap edits and correct them if you wish.

Comment: @indivisible: I'm more irritated that there was a reviewer that approved it than I am about the edit itself...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why we reject suggested edits as too minor is because people have to review those edits, and it's not worth the time to go and review such minor things.

Don't make the problem worse and waste extra time worrying about minor edits that actually did make it through.

---

If you truly care about the quality of edits then you yourself should personally go make a suggested edit which fixes the rest of the post.  Don't worry about policing other people.

Comment: Agreed, in principle.  Don't throw good money after bad.  Don't trip over dollars to get to pennies, etc. etc.